# how to send mach message to windowserver

Tags: macos

I want to use the `mach_msg` to send some mach message to windowserver.
but I do not know the `msg.msgh_remote_port` of windowserver.

where can i get the remote_port of windowserver,so that, i can call some function 
such as `_XSetGlobalForceConfig` in the CoreGraphics.Framework

thks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the service name of the process you want to connect to, the port can be looked up with a call to `bootstrap_look_up`.

As of 10.10, launchd source is no longer available, but you can find the header still present in 10.9 [here](http://opensource.apple.com/source/launchd/launchd-842.92.1/liblaunch/bootstrap.h).

Comment: Thank you ：），I will have a try